# Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object Error After Registration

Tags: php, laravel

After Registration I got this Error, SMTP Setup is Also Works Perfect
Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object in "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php"

In this Function

```
protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $config = config('session');

        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie(
                'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
            )
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

Here Is RedirectIfAuthenticated.Php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably not in the code you shared. At some point you must have other middleware (not shared here) that does not return a response object

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was unable to find the solution. While debugging I realized that I am using `auth:api` middleware for protected paths when I should have been using `auth` middleware instead.

I had this

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')
```

and changed to this

```
Route::middleware('auth')
```

and the exception was gone.